# Type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'FutureOr<List<RideData>>', Flutter

Tags: flutter, mobile, flutter-provider, flutter-futurebuilder

I'm calling an API but I've been trying to parse this `JSON` response correctly but I haven't been able to resolve this issue. I call the API, and want to display the data with a `FutureBuilder` and `Provider`, but I get that error `Type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'FutureOr<List<RideData>>'` and I'm not sure what am I doing wrong. The code is below:

API Call:

```
  Future<List<RideData>> getRides() async {
    final response = await HTTP.apiRequest(Method.GET, '/rides');
    final data = jsonDecode(response.body)['data'];
    return data;
  }
```

The Future builder where I want to display the data:

```
 Future<List<RideData>> _getRideStreamList() async {
    final _vehicleStreamData = await APICall.instance.getRides();
    var provider = Provider.of<RideStore>(context, listen: false);
    provider.setVehicleList(_vehicleStreamData, notify: false);
    return _vehicleStreamData;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: SafeArea(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Container(
                height: 1000,
                child: FutureBuilder<List<RideData>>(
                  future: _getRideStreamList(),
                  builder: (context, snapshot) {
                    if (snapshot.hasData) {
                      Consumer<RideStore>(
                        builder: (context, rideData, child) {
                          return ListView.builder(
                            shrinkWrap: true,
                            itemCount: rideData.rideList.length,
                            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                              RideData rides = rideData.getRideByIndex(index);
                              return Text('${rides.rideId}');
                            },
                          );
                        },
                      );
                    } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                      return Text("${snapshot.error}");
                    }
                    return Container();
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

I am almost certain that the issue with the API call and the response because I'm not parsing the JSON data correctly but maybe I'm wrong and something else is the issue...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make Model class of RideData then

```
Future<List<RideData>> getRides() async {
        final response = await HTTP.apiRequest(Method.GET, '/rides');
        List<dynamic> data = jsonDecode(response.body)['data'];
        List<YourModelClass> list = [];
        if (response.data != null) {
          list = data.map((item) => YourModelClass.fromJson(item)).toList();
        }
        return list;
      }
```

You can generate model class
https://javiercbk.github.io/json_to_dart/

Answer (score 0):

this line

```
    final data = jsonDecode(response.body)['data'];
```

you are taking data and decoding it and it returns a map or string, not any list or any models.... you should create a List of RideData first then return it

you can follow this approach

```
List<RideData> list = List<RideData>();
    if (response.data != null) {
      list = data.map((item) => RideData.fromJson(item)).toList();
    }
    return list;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

And, on top of the other problems pointed out, you're doing this:

```
future: _getRideStreamList(),
```

Never never never *build* the future you're watching as part of building the FutureBuilder.  Infinite loops!  Read the docs for FutureBuilder, especially paying attention to the second and third paragraphs.  Same goes for StreamBuilder.  I have a video about that https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sqE-J8YJnpg to illustrate why the docs do not lie.